# Does Adobe Have A Startup Program Similar to Microsoft's BizSpark?

Tags: adobe, startup

Microsoft's BizSpark is an excellent program that helps startups get going. I was wondering if Adobe or other companies had a similar program?

Comment: I believe it's called Microsoft BizSpark actually.  http://www.microsoft.com/BizSpark/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing developer and designer tools, and not about using those tools for software development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the same, but Adobe does have [Adobe Ventures](http://www.adobe.com/aboutadobe/adobeventures/). They plan on investing $100 million over the next five years in startups that utilize Adobe platforms.